# how to display just three articles per row using bulma css tiles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, bulma

in bulma css tiles wont support multiline like columns do. so all articles are showing in the same row, but i just want to display three articles per row. below is the code in my gatsbyjs blog page right now. need to insert some code for every three iterations?

```
        <div className="tile is-ancestor">
            {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map((edge)=> {
                return(
                    <div className="tile is-parent is-4">
                      <div className="tile is-child notification">
                      <p className="is-7">{edge.node.frontmatter.date}</p>
                      <h2 className="subtitle is-5">{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                      <p>{edge.node.excerpt}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    // code i used to chunk the array
    const chunk = (arr, size) =>
    Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
      arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
    );
    let chunks = chunk(data.allMarkdownRemark.edges, 3);
```

and found the final solution is here in this thread. thanks everyone :)
[map() method on multi dimensional array in gatsby/react, getting error while trying to wrap inner loop in div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62587657/13804553)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157562/5385381

Comment: @ksav thanks. looping through two dimensional array, great idea. but i was able to make it into chunks in java script and able to log to the console successfully. but couldn't able to get the desired output in gatsby/react its too confusing n overwhelming for me es6 syntax  :(

Comment: Feel free to update the question with the chunked array.

Comment: @ksav thanks a lot, your reply guided me in the right direction.  achieved my goal :) here is the final solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62587814/13804553

Comment: @deep you might want to post the solution as an answer to this question so if people come across your question here, they find the solution immediately.