# map() method on multi dimensional array in gatsby/react, getting error while trying to wrap inner loop in div

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, gatsby, bulma

i want to display three posts per row in a gatsbyjs web page. i am having an array of posts, if i were to display using columns it would be just applying the multiline class on the posts container div. but i am using tiles layout built-in in bulma css, unfortunately that don't support multiline likes columns do.

so i have to wrap every three posts in a div with class 'tile'.  for which i split the array into chunks of 3 size each (as suggested by someone here, thanks to him) now it boiled down to looping through a two dimensional array.

now the problem is i am getting syntax error when trying to wrap the inner loop in a div (i am new to javascript/es6 and react/gatsby, so i am hoping someone here would help me out) below is the code, i commented out the divs for which i am getting error. so how to wrap the inner loop in a div in gatsby/react. TIA

```
return(
        <div className="tile is-ancestor">
               {chunks.map((chunk)=> {
                 return (
                   //<div class="tile">
                      chunk.map((edge) => {
                          return(
                            <div className="tile is-parent is-4">
                              <div className={`tile is-child notification ${edge.node.frontmatter.type}`}>
                              <p className="is-7">{edge.node.frontmatter.date}</p>
                              <h2 className="subtitle is-5">{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                              <p>{edge.node.excerpt}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )
                        }
                      )
                    //</div>
                    )
            })}
        </div>
);
```

Comment: would be interesting to know what "syntax error" you are getting

Comment: what is probably a problem, that you use class in commented div, but should use className (like you do in other html)

Comment: @StefanWuthrich-Altafino changing class to className didn't work and the error msg is -
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token 
pointing at the  inner loop return()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to wrap the code inside that div in curly braces { } to be valid JSX. Just like you did with the first chunks.map.

```html
return(
        <div className="tile is-ancestor">
               {chunks.map((chunk)=> {
                 return (
                   <div class="tile">
                    {
                      chunk.map((edge) => {
                          return(
                            <div className="tile is-parent is-4">
                              <div className={`tile is-child notification ${edge.node.frontmatter.type}`}>
                              <p className="is-7">{edge.node.frontmatter.date}</p>
                              <h2 className="subtitle is-5">{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                              <p>{edge.node.excerpt}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )
                        }
                      )
                     }
                    </div>
                    )
            })}
        </div>
);
```